# How to update all images to be of a specific type only

Tags: sql, image, binary, informix

If I have a table `empimage` with the following structure:

```
emp_num INT,
emp_image BYTE in pics,
thumb BYTE in pics
```

Some images are `jpg`:
The `emp_image` data field starts with the following:

```
FFD8FFE000104A464946000101010060...
```

Some images are `png` for example:
The `emp_image` data field starts with the following:

```
89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452...
```

My question is how to update all my images `emp_image` to be `jpg` in this table, I mean to start like this:

```
FFD8FFE000104A464946000101010060...
```

Comment: I cannot imagine there's some built in image converter in your DBMS. So I guess you'd need to write some program that fetches all non JPEG images, converts them to JPEG (using an appropriate library) and pushes the JPEG data back into the database. Or you'd need to code some image converter into the database, but that's the harder way I guess.

Comment: @stickybit : I notice a pattern where all `jpg` binary begins with specific chars `FFD8FFE000104A464946000101010060`, why I can't write an update statement to override the first chars of non `jpg` to the common of `jpg`

Comment: Because that won't (in general) produce a valid JPEG and that is your goal, isn't it? You'd just end up with more or less random binary data. If the data is that unimportant that this would be acceptable then why converting it in the first place? You could just discard it then.

Comment: @stickybit excuse me, I can't imagine, If I have two fields `x & y,` and `x= 7-say`,`y= 9-opla`,
Why converting `y = 7-opla` makes it invalid

Comment: You should invest some time to at least briefly read upon image file formats (or file formats in general). They store the information in often very different ways. They may use different color depths for the pixels for example. Or they use color palettes instead of directly providing a pixels color. They use different compression algorithms. And the data for the same pixel might be stored somewhere upfront in one format more to the end in an other, etc.. And especially the beginning of a file might give vital information on how the rest is to be interpreted, where things begin and end e.g..

Comment: Or just open an PNG file on you computer in a hexeditor and see what it looks like when you just change the beginning to a JPEG header, if it's even rendered by your image viewer and not completely rejected. Unlike you hit some very edge case you'll end up with garbage.

Comment: You should tag the images with a field that identifies whether they are PNG or JPEG files (or any other type).  This is especially a problem since you can't use substring operations (either the SUBSTR function or the subscript range notation) to extract data from a BYTE field for comparisons — not to mention the difficulty of representing bytes with codes 0xFF, 0xD8, etc in a string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this means that I can’t do update operation depending on these different codes